# Twitter "message to" & "tweet to" tabs under profile pic

Tags: twitter

New to twitter, I see many people's profile pages with "message to" & "tweet to" under their profile pic. I do not see anything in settings or edit profile where I can add these tabs or buttons? Not sure if it's custom and would like to add them to my new Twitter page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure these only appear when you are viewing someone else's account, because you can't message or tweet to yourself! When someone else views your account, the "Tweet to" button will appear automatically. The "Message" button appearance depends on that person's privacy settings (it is set for public or set for followers or for none).

Here's how to see this in action: Next time you're with a friend, ask them to log into their own Twitter account. Then have them browse to your account. Are the "message to" and "tweet to" buttons there?

Comment: This is the answer. I checked one of my Twitter accounts with the other, and the "Tweet to" button was there, but I didn't do anything special. Obviously it wasn't on my own profile, nor was it on a profile when I visited with an incognito window, because I wasn't logged in.

Comment: That's great news! You can mark my answer as "the answer"; there's a check box or something.

Comment: I'm not the Asker. I was merely confirming what you've found

Comment: _you can't message to yourself._ You Can.

Comment: @serenesat Hey, I just tried that and you're right! What a weird feature. Anyway, I should have clarified in my answer that there weren't buttons to tweet to yourself or message yourself, but you can do it "manually".

Comment: @BrettFromLA : One more information about message was wrong in your answer, I have corrected it.